# java8 stream doesn't change a class member

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have this code:

```
Set<String> namesSet = new HashSet<>();

@Override
public boolean isValid(List<String> input) {
    input.stream().map(item -> namesSet.add(item));
    return namesSet.size() == input.size();
}
```

`input` is a list with one item.

How come this item is not added to the namesSet after the `stream::map` ?

**update** here is my fix:

```
Set<String> namesSet;

@Override
public boolean isValid(List<String> input) {
    namesSet = new HashSet<>();
    input.stream().forEach(item -> namesSet.add(item));
    return namesSet.size() == input.size();
}
```

Comment: Stream are not intended to change something. They are designed to evaluate to a result. And `map` should, as its name tell, map from a value to another, not modify something. Hence, without an actual *terminal operation* that evaluates a result, nothing will happen. It would be stupid, if Streams were designed to just provide you a more verbose way of saying `namesSet.addAll(input);`…

Comment: Your “fixed” code still is obsolete Stream use. Just use `namesSet = new HashSet<>(input); return namesSet.size() == input.size();`. If you want to bring in Streams at all costs, the clean way is `namesSet = input.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet()); return namesSet.size() == input.size();`.

Comment: or `input.stream().distinct().count() == input.size()`. And remove that redundant field.

Comment: @Jaroslaw Pawlak: that’s the right thing if the `Set` is not used otherwise.

Comment: @Holger `isValid` method modifying a field? It doesn't sound like a nice side effect. https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~susan/475/unmain.html - see point 3 ;)

Comment: @Jaroslaw Pawlak: you don’t have to convince *me*…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stream operations are lazy and won't execute unless you close a terminal operation such as `forEach` or `collect`.

Use `forEach` instead of `map` in this case. `map` is an intermediate operation.

By the way, it sounds like very nasty side effect that your `isValid` method modifies the field. If you call it once and get `true`, on the second call you will get `false`. Anyway, I cannot quite understand this method - because (once you fix it) it will be always returning `true` on first call and `false` on all subsequent calls. The only exception is empty list, in which case it will always return `true`.

**EDIT:**

Having a closer look at your method, if you just want to find whether list contains duplicates, you can just do:

```
input.stream().distinct().count() == input.size()
```

Comment: The OP shouldn’t use `forEach` for this task. If `namesSet.addAll(input);` is the desired operation, it should be written as such, without the unnecessary use of the Stream API.

Comment: @Holger Honestly, the whole method is a code smell, as I wrote in the last paragraph.

Comment: Looking at it again, it’s more awkward. The result depends on whether the list elements are unique and/or the set previously contained values. For an initially empty set, calling it multiple times with the same list, containing unique values only will yield `true` each time. Other scenarios can lead to arbitrary inconsistent results.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem, the use of Stream API is *not necessary.*

Just create a `Set` with the content of your `List` (using `HashSet`s *[copy constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet(java.util.Collection))*) and compare sizes:

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(List<String> input) {
    Set<String> namesSet = new HashSet<>(input); // copies the content of 'input'
    return namesSet.size() == input.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps).

"Intermediate operations return a new stream. They are always lazy; executing an intermediate operation such as filter() does not actually perform any filtering, but instead creates a new stream that, when traversed, contains the elements of the initial stream that match the given predicate. Traversal of the pipeline source does not begin until the terminal operation of the pipeline is executed."

So you need to call a terminal operation.